# Issues with mod_rewrite // Apache 2.2 // OpenSUSE 11.3

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, opensuse

Apache Installed OK, LoadModule mod_rewrite is already uncommented in etc/apache2/httpd.conf, we've uncommented AllowOverrides and followed standard procedure for what is quite a simple install but .htaccess files are still taking no effect - are there any specific requirements for the setup above that would mean the mod_rewrite isn't working?

phpinfo() shows that mod_rewrite is loaded but we simply can't make any .htaccess file work, even with the simplest tests

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^link([^/]*).html$ testrule.php?link=$1 [L]
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: http://anl4u.com/?p=1162 This is the answer - the one single blog on the net with the answer!!! SuSEconfig is the issue!

Comment: Did you try to put the rewrite rules into the virtual host declaration first? That would tell you if your problem is with subdirectories .htaccess or not.

Answer (score 1):

Another test to see if it's running is

```
lsof | grep mod_rewrite
```

I found after adding the 'rewrite' to the conf file and running the update

```
SuSEconfig
```

it still wasn't loading so I added it manually to this file as well

/etc/apache2/sysconfig.d/loadmodule.conf

After restarting apache all is working!

Answer (score 0):

AllowOverrides could also be configured inside Directory tag, may be AllowOverrides is uncommented and On globally but is explicitly off in Directory tag.

Just a comment based on the provided information, it would be great if you could paste the related part of your httpd.conf.